# Where can I get a transcript of the past chat cast discussions?

Tags: discussion, chat-sessions

For those who have not been flowing along, we have been having weekly chat discussions about about site policy and content.

Here is a list of bookmarks from the previous chat cast session for those that wish to follow.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best if this were an answer?

Answer (score 2):

### Chat casts are as follows

#### Chat Cast #1 – 1/20/13

- Side α: [List questions, how should they be handled?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/list-questions-brainstorming-2013-01-30)
- Side β: [How can we attract more new users to our site?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/member-recruitment-brainstorming-session-2013-01-30)

---

#### Chat Cast #2 – 02/02/13

- Side α: [What should be in out FAQ and About page?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/faq-phrasing-brainstorming-session-2013-02-02)
- Side β: [What should we do about the "Anime vs. Cartoon" question and others like it?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/the-cartoon-question-2013-02-02)
- Side γ: [Should we modify anime-identification tag to include other media such as manga?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/retagging-of-the-anime-identification-tag-2013-02-02)

---

#### Chat Cast #3 – 02/09/13

- Side α: [What can we do to promote our site?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/third-chat-cast-site-promotion-2013-02-09)
- Side β: [What should we do about anime questions posted on other SEs (notably SciFi)?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/third-chat-cast-offtopic-anime-questions-on-other-sites-2013-02-09)
- Side γ: [Should we expand our scope to include questions based on anime-style media (including games)?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/third-chat-cast-expanding-our-scope-2013-02-09)

---

#### Chat Cast #4 – 02/16/13

- Side α: [Certain meta tags are affecting SEO to the site. What should we do about it?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/meta-tags-4-chat-cast)
- Side β: [What should we do about the management of content on Facebook and Twitter?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/content-managing-for-fb-and-g-4-chat-cast)
- Side γ: [How should we handle matters of copyright on our site?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/copyright-material-in-posts-4-chat-cast) – *Community moderator response*
- Side δ: [How should we use copyrighted material in out community ads?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/more-on-copyright-4-chat-cast) – *Community moderator response*

---

#### Chat Cast #5 – 03/02/13

- Side α: [Question that ask for information not yet revealed in still ongoing series. What should we do about it?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/questions-on-ongoing-series-5-chat-cast)
- Side β: [What should we do about the management of content on Facebook and Twitter?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/content-of-social-pages-5-chat-cast) - *Continued*
- Side γ: [The "manga paper question".](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/the-manga-paper-question-5-chat-cast)
- Side δ: [What can we do to attract more users? Debate over a possible community effort.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/community-effort-to-get-more-users-5-chat-cast)

---

#### Chat Cast #6 – 03/16/13

- Side α: [What types of content should we post on out community pages to help promote the site and generate interest?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/sixth-chat-cast-content-for-social-media-promotion)
- Side β: [What should we do about genre tags and tags of series that follow different continuities?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/sixth-cast-cast-genre-tags-and-series-tag-continuity)

---

#### Chat Cast #7 – 05/25/13

- Side α: [List questions revisited: How should we deal with out-of-universe questions?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/list-questions-revisited-how-to-deal-with-in-and-out-of-univese-questions-7)

---

If you wish to participate in future chat casts (which typically happen on Saturdays), please check the pinned notifications in our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga) for the time as it is subject to change. You may also register [here to receive notifications](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/anime-and-manga?tab=schedule) a reminder for the chat cast events as they become available.

If you cannot make a chat cast, but would still like to participate, feel free to ping [a moderator](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and we can see if we can work something out.